# Accessing attributes of an object related model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, models

I've recently started working on a golf website and ran into an issue that I can't seem to comprehend.  I have two models, an `Event` model and a `Round` model.  An `Event` is set up with one or more `Rounds`.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :round

class Round < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :event
```

In my home page, I want to display the next event and then display attributes from the round(s) associated with the event such as `start_time`, `fees`, etc.  In this case, we are only playing one round for the upcoming event.

I am able to get the next event but I don't understand how to access the rounds associated with the events.

In my `HomeController`, I have the following:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    layout "home"

    def index
        @event = Event.next
    end
end
```

It was my understanding that having a has_many and belongs_to association would allow me to use the instance in my view like `@event.rounds.start_time` to get the `start_time` for the round associated with the instance of `@event`.

What am I missing?

Thanks,

Memo

Answer (score 1):

`@event.rounds` is an array. If you want to get the `start_time` of the first element from the array -- use `@event.rounds.first.start_time`. Or you can get all start times by this: `@event.rounds.map(&:start_time)`.

Also change `has_many :round` to `has_many :rounds` in the event model.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response SD.  I tried that but I keep getting undefined method `rounds' for #<Event:0x007f87b56e1e70>.  I do have event_id in the Rounds table.

Comment: Thanks again. I did have the event_id and I think I'm getting closer to the problem.  I was able to successfully call "@events.rounds.first.start_time" as you mentioned if I found "@event" using Event.find(1).  What I've been doing is calling a scope named "next" that I have defined in my Event model. scope :next, lambda { where('start_date >= ?', Date.today).limit(1) }.  Apparently, this is not including my association with rounds.

Answer (score 0):

@Speransky Danil - That did not work but I was able to get a work around using the following although I feel like I have an extra call to the database.

@event = Event.find(Event.next)

As I mentioned before, if I do a find by ID I am able to access the rounds associate with the event but if I try to use a scope such as the one below, I can not.

scope :next, lambda { where('start_date >= ?', Date.today).limit(1) }

This is the error I keep getting.

```
     NoMethodError: undefined method `rounds' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fa40f3bdcf0>
from /Users/Memo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:45:in `method_missing'
from (irb):24
from /Users/Memo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/Memo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/Memo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I will go with this for now in order to move on and add a TODO.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

My Events call Event.next will retrieve an array even though I limit to 1 record.  So based on that I had to change my call to:

@event.first.rounds.first.start_time